# Trying to add nexmo CallerID to voice_api script

Tags: api, voice, vonage

I am a beginner with nexmo. Using the nexmo voice-api. I have created a basic script that does the following:

Goal:

```
$from number (xxx xxx 0000) // nexmo number
$to number  (xxx xxx 1111) //office desk phone
$connect number (xxx xxx 2222) //destination phone
```

nexmo script does this...

1 - $from (nexmo number) calls $to (office phone)
2 - $to picks up and text says connecting call
3 - then dials $connect

Current Issue: to change the CallerID that is now showing the $from (nexmo number) and have the CallerID show instead as the $to (office phone) number.

I was hoping for something simple like adding a 'CallerID' tag like below... so that the destination call would see the caller id from the OFFICE phone not the nexmo phone...

Is this possible somehow?

```
    //ORIGINAL SCRIPT
//
$from = 'xxxxxx1111';
$to = 'xxxxxx2222';
$connect = 'xxxxxx3333';require_once "vendor/autoload.php";$keypair = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Keypair(
file_get_contents('private.key'),
'xxxxxx'
);$client = new \Nexmo\Client($keypair);$ncco = [[
'action' => 'talk',
'voiceName' => 'Nicole',
'text' => 'Connecting your call now.'
],[
'action' => 'connect',
'eventUrl' => ["https://example.com/webhooks/update.php"],
'from' => 'xxxxxx1111',

// add somethinhg simple like this?
'??? CallerID ???' => $to, 
//'xxxxxx2222 office phone here'

'endpoint'  =>  [['type' => 'phone','number' => $connect]]
]];try {$call = new \Nexmo\Call\Call();$call->setTo($to)
->setFrom($from)
->setNcco($ncco);$response = $client->calls()->create($call);
echo $response->getId();
}
catch (exception $e) {
    //code to handle the exception    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
finally {
    //optional code that always runs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the $from number to the $to number. the $from parameter can be set to any valid phone number

Comment: Thanks Tony for your help. 

In this case the $from number is the nexmo number that dials the $to office number first. Then, when the Office number picks up it dials the $connect number.

I wanted the office person to get the first call so that the connect number doesn't have to wait.

But are you suggesting that the $to Office number should call the $connect number first then call the $to Office number second if they pick up?


All I am looking for is that the connect call sees the callerID from the office phone - not the nexmo number. Is this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: if you are just looking to show a different number when calling a user, you can set $from to whatever number you like. So when the first call is connected, you make a new call to a new number correct? if so, in that second call, you should be able to set the $from param to the 'to' parameter when the call is answered

Comment: when the first call is answered, you should receive the `to` and `from` query parameters from the answer webhook.

Comment: Hi Tony - Thanks for the suggestions.

I just made this change:

`

//I changed the 
'from' => 'xxxxxx1111', //(nexmo phone)
//and tried
'from' => 'xxxxxx2222', //(office phone)

//like this:

[
'action' => 'connect',
'eventUrl' => ["https://example.com/webhooks/update.php"],
'from' => 'xxxxxx2222',
'endpoint'  =>  [['type' => 'phone','number' => $connect]]
]

`

Comment: The connection did go through however the calledID came in as 'Private' with no number on the other end calledID - so that's not the best.
 
 
- Now I am thinking that maybe there's a way to register the actual vonage office phone numbers with nexmo and then calledID can go through not as 'private' calls with no numbers - but as a regular call and actual vonage number?

Comment: @revbiz So I just found out from a colleague that this isn't possible at the moment.